# Can't connect to internet CentOS7 NAT

Tags: linux, centos, nat

I'm using a CENTOS7 client with Virtualbox. I have 2 NIC's connected.
The first one is on internat network (IP 192.168.1.254) and the other one is on NAT (IP 10.0.3.15)
I was able to ping to google.com on the client, but suddenly it stopped working.

Someone maybe knows how to fix this weird problem?

Thx

Comment: Vbox network configuration screenshots and outputs of ifconfig/traceroute commands would be useful to help you.

Comment: if the internal network doesnt have internet then its possible that linux is bouncing between the 2 nics. disable the internal nic and see if it works again.

Comment: show output of `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-em1` and replace `em1` with whatever the actual nic is, which you can get from running `ifconfig -a`